# True or False and why ? basic integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^2 f(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$

I would say true because a&b = a&b and it would not make a change if is x,d,f,q,w,t it will logically be all the same, am I right ? but because it is MATH not logic so everything could be unexpected!

Comment: If $u=x$ then $du=dx$

Answer (score 3):

It is of course true, because in a definite integral, the variable of integration is often just considered a "dummy variable".

Let's say the indefinite integral is $F(x) + c_1$ in one case, and obviously, $F(t) + c_2$ in the other, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

In both cases, the definite integral would work out to be $F(2) - F(0)$. The constants always vanish in a definite integral so they are irrelevant.

Comment: Nice explanation. Upshot is that, regardless of the variable name, you end up substituting definite values for it, erasing any "memory" of the variable used to perform the integration. Good, +1.